# GIMP - Gmic's plugin on windows not working

Tags: gimp

With GIMP-2.8 I have installed Gmic's plugin. I tried both Installer for x64 bit and also tried zip. Not worked (Not showing Gmac's plugin in Filter Menu) any method after restart. Also not showing any error. I followed installation notes [provided here](https://gmic.eu/download.shtml), did not worked. Is there any way to check what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not an answer but too big for comment. If you click the "Important installation note for GIMP 2.8 on Windows!" you see:

> The Windows version of the G'MIC plug-in for GIMP 2.8 comes with a bunch of .DLL files that may be incompatible with those provided with your installation of GIMP. To avoid possible DLL conflicts, our installer thus copies all his files into a new subfolder, located in your user's plug-in directory, You have then to explicitly add this subfolder as a recognized plug-in folder in the GIMP preferences to make sure GIMP can detect and run the plug-in.

Have you done this? Got to  *Edit>Preferences>Folders>Plug-ins*, then in the panel on the right you can add a folder.

Comment: I did it, not worked though. With new version of gimp it works fine. I am still looking for solution because porting to new version may break work done in older version.